# Warning : Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Tags: python, pandas

I sliced a part of a dataframe to keep only two columns.

```
description_category = titles[['listed_in','description']]
```

the extract look like that

```
description_category.head()

    Listed_in                                           description
0   International TV Shows, TV Dramas, TV Sci-Fi &...   In a future where the elite inhabit an island ...
1   Dramas, International Movies                        After a devastating earthquake hits Mexico Cit...
2   Horror Movies, International Movies                 When an army recruit is found dead, his fellow...
3   Action & Adventure, Independent Movies, Sci-Fi...   In a postapocalyptic world, rag-doll robots hi...
4   Dramas                                              A brilliant group of students become card-coun...
```

What I want to do is to put in [,] each theme in the column "Listed_in", so it looks like that :

```
    listed_in                                           description
0   [International TV Shows, TV Dramas, TV Sci-Fi ...   In a future where the elite inhabit an island ...
1   [Dramas, International Movies]                      After a devastating earthquake hits Mexico Cit...
2   [Horror Movies, International Movies]               When an army recruit is found dead, his fellow...
3   [Action & Adventure, Independent Movies, Sci-F...   In a postapocalyptic world, rag-doll robots hi...
4   [Dramas]                                            A brilliant group of students become card-coun...
```

I tried this, but it showed me a warning :

```
description_category['listed_in'] = description_category['listed_in'].apply(lambda x: x.split(', '))
```

Warning :

```
C:\Anaconda\envs\nlp_course\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

I check few threads on that issue, but I am still not able to fix it.

What do you suggest me to do?

Let me know if you need more background to my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make a new dataframe while keeping `titles`, then

- either slice with `.loc[]`:

  ```py
  description_category = titles.loc[:, ['listed_in', 'description']]
  ```
- or create a `.copy()`:

  ```py
  description_category = titles[['listed_in', 'description']].copy()
  ```

Also it's faster to use [`.str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) instead of `apply()`:

```py
description_category['listed_in'] = description_category['listed_in'].str.split(', ')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.. it will work!!
Wrap up the entire task with DataFrame.loc[ ]`

```
description_category.loc[description_category['listed_in'] = description_category['listed_in'].apply(lambda x: x.split(', '))]
```

It won't show any warning